# Translate js with WPML & Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wpml

I'm trying to translate a custom plugin I bought.
Now I need to translate some text in js. How would I go about doing this?

I have 2 lines I would like to translate:

```
if (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        var result_html = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> Please wait for the page to reload.</div>';
        jQuery("#result_msg").html(result_html);
        refresh_table_entry();
        setTimeout(function () {// wait for 5 secs(2)
```

"Success! Please wait for the page to reload." This is what I would like to be translatable here.

```
if (data) {
    var tblhtml = '<thead> <tr> <th>   <label for="selectAll">#</label></th> <th>Product Key</th><th>Created at</th> </tr> </thead>'; // loop the array, and do whatever you want to do
    var i = 1;
    jQuery.each(data.result, function (key, value) {
```

"Product Key" & "Created at" should be translatable aswell.

I'm a complete noob with js and PHP, that's why I would greatly appreciate any kind of help!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, if you bought this plugin why not ask its developer to make this text translatable? They probably know how to do this, and since you paid for the plugin and it's a minor change they might not mind helping out. Otherwise, next time you update it (assuming you can) any changes made to its code will be lost.

Comment: I cant contact the developer. The plugin does not need any updates. Thats why im comfortable changing that stuff. I just need to know how...

Comment: In that case, here's how you make JavaScript strings translatable: [I18N for WordPress Developers - Handling JavaScript files](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Handling_JavaScript_files).